# Problem uploading file with extention method in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a registration form in which every user can send his information along with a upload file to the server. Although I did not define the Required field, the form will not be sent until a file is uploaded for selection. I think there is a problem with the controller code,

The code I wrote in the controller is:

```
         public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include =" ID,FullName,Mellicode,PostTime,Mobile,Telephone,Email,Age,Gender,Address,Postalcode,LastEducationalCertificate,FieldOfStudy,JobExperience,MaritalStatus,Comment,FilePathName,Invitation,Invalidity,Recruitment")] RegisterForm registerForm, HttpPostedFileBase UploadFile)

            {

        var myUniqueFileName = string.Format(@"{0}.txt",Guid.NewGuid());


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             string strFileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(UploadFile.FileName).ToUpper();


            string strContentType = UploadFile.ContentType.ToUpper();

                    if (UploadFile.ContentLength > 100 * 1024)
                {
                           return View("Error");
            }

            else if(UploadFile.ContentLength<100*1024 && UploadFile !=null) 
            {
                registerForm.FilePathName = myUniqueFileName + UploadFile.FileName;

                if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(strPath) == false)
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(strPath);
                }

                string strPathName =
                    string.Format("{0}\\{1}", strPath, registerForm.FilePathName);

                UploadFile.SaveAs(strPathName);
            }

            db.Registers.Add(registerForm);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Back");
        }
        return View(registerForm);
        }
```

To upload, the following extension method is also used:

```
         public static class UploadHelper
       {
public static MvcHtmlString Upload(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    //helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression))
    TagBuilder input = new TagBuilder("input");
    input.Attributes.Add("type", "file");
    input.Attributes.Add("id", helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(name));
    input.Attributes.Add("name", helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name));
    input.Attributes.Add("class", "required");


    if (htmlAttributes != null)
    {
        var attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        input.MergeAttributes(attributes);
    }

    return new MvcHtmlString(input.ToString());
}
```

}

code view upload:

```
          <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FilePathName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-10" })
                  <div class="col-md-10">
                      @Html.Upload("UploadFile", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control demoInputBox ", type = "file", runat = "server" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FilePathName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                  </div>
              </div>

          </div>
```

I want to use this method if someone can give me some thanks

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: What issue are you having when you try to use it, exactly?

Comment: The form is sent when I upload a file to the upload field
But when the file is not uploaded, the form will not be sent, although this upload field is not required.

Comment: You are adding `input.Attributes.Add("class", "required");` ...so maybe this causes some JS to detect it and treat it as required?

Comment: I want to send the form without uploading. The field  defined in the model class:

Comment: [Display (Name = "fileupload")]

public string FilePathName {get; set; }

Comment: Try it without "input.Attributes.Add("class", "required"); " in the Upload helper class.